# Show attachment message in a sequence format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page, on which if I submit the form without adding the attachment,
I get message as ***"Please attach file for .., .., .., "***

But now I want to show that in a sequence like below:-

Please attach file for

**SR.No  AttachmentName   Attached(Y/N)**

1. passport               Y

Here is my code below:-

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtAttach = new DataTable();

    List<string> attachMan = new List<string>();
    string strerrmsg = string.Empty;
    attachMan.Add("Birth Certificate~BC");
    attachMan.Add("PAN Certificate~PNC");
    attachMan.Add("UAN Certificate~UAN");
    attachMan.Add("Gratuity Certificate~GRAT");
    attachMan.Add("Nomination Certificate~NOC");
    attachMan.Add("Permanent Address~RAC");
    if (txtHouseNumber_Per.Text + txtStreetNumber_Per.Text + txtArea_Per.Text + txtLandMark_Per.Text + txtCity_Per.Text + txtPinCode_Per.Text +
         txtState_Per.Text + txtTelephoneNum_Per.Text + txtMobileNum_Per.Text !=
         txtHouseNum_M.Text + txtStreetNum_M.Text + txtArea_M.Text + txtLandmark_M.Text + txtCity_M.Text + txtPinCode_M.Text +
         txtState_M.Text + txtTelephoneNum_M.Text + txtMobileNumber_M.Text)
    {
        attachMan.Add("Mailing Address Proof~PAC");
    }
    if (TxtPassportNo.Text != "") attachMan.Add("Passport~PC");

    for (int i = 0; i < attachMan.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] arrMsg = attachMan[i].Split(new char[] { '~' });
        string strmsg = CF.ExecuteScaler("select count(*) from EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS " +
                                        "where pk1_value = '" + txtEmpCode.Text + "' and " +
                                        "category_id in ('" + arrMsg[1] + "')");
        if (strmsg == "0") strerrmsg += arrMsg[0] + ", ";
    }

    if (strerrmsg != "")
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CloseScript", "alert('Please Attach file for " + strerrmsg.ToString() + " ');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        funsave();
    }
}
```

Please suggest what to do

Comment: Do you want to show a message on the page instead of an alert ?

Comment: Just an FYI, there is an SQL Injection risk in your SQL Statement. You should use bind variables to mitigate this risk.  More Info: http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html

Comment: @ramhemasri: No, i want to show the message on **alert** only.

Comment: @nadeem... You need to show just `Please Attach file for passport Y` instead of `Please Attach file for Birth Certificate, PAN Certificate, UAN Certificate, Gratuity Certificate, Nomination Certificate, Permanent Address, Passport, ` right?

Comment: @user2946329: Yes, but if _more than one attachment_ message has to be shown then, it should be in the sequence which I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @nadeem ... Please explain a bit more ... When more than one attachment message has to be shown?  If you could show a more complete example it would be more easy to solve your problem.

Comment: @user2946329: See, if I click on the submit button leaving two mandatory attachment. Then it should show message like below:-

**Please attach file for**
**attachmentname   Status
Passport              Pending
Birth Certicate      Pending**


Also, the filename which has been attached, it should show that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried myself on this to get an answer. The things were needed to change a bit, but I finally managed to handle it.

Here I go:-

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtAttach = new DataTable(); string strpmsg = "";

    List<string> attachMan = new List<string>();
    string strerrmsg = string.Empty;
    attachMan.Add("Birth Certificate~BC");
    attachMan.Add("PAN Certificate~PNC");
    attachMan.Add("UAN Certificate~UAN");
    attachMan.Add("Gratuity Certificate~GRAT");
    attachMan.Add("Nomination Certificate~NOC");
    attachMan.Add("Permanent Address~RAC");
    if (txtHouseNumber_Per.Text + txtStreetNumber_Per.Text + txtArea_Per.Text + txtLandMark_Per.Text +
         txtCity_Per.Text + txtPinCode_Per.Text + txtState_Per.Text + txtTelephoneNum_Per.Text + txtMobileNum_Per.Text !=
         txtHouseNum_M.Text + txtStreetNum_M.Text + txtArea_M.Text + txtLandmark_M.Text +
         txtCity_M.Text + txtPinCode_M.Text + txtState_M.Text + txtTelephoneNum_M.Text + txtMobileNumber_M.Text)
    {
        attachMan.Add("Mailing Address Proof~PAC");
    }
    if (TxtPassportNo.Text != "") attachMan.Add("Passport~PC");

    for (int i = 0; i < attachMan.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] arrMsg = attachMan[i].Split(new char[] { '~' });
        string strmsg = CF.ExecuteScaler("select count(*) from EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS " +
                                         "where pk1_value = '" + txtEmpCode.Text + "' and " +
                                         "category_id in ('" + arrMsg[1] + "')");

        if (strmsg == "0") 
        {
            strerrmsg += (i + 1).ToString() + ".  " + arrMsg[0] + "  (pending)\\n";   **// Pending message**
            strpmsg = "pending";
        }
        else
        {
            strerrmsg += (i + 1).ToString() + ".  " + arrMsg[0] + "  (attached)\\n";  **// Attached message**
        }
    }

    //  string condition1 = ""; string condition2 = "";
    /* if (txtHouseNumber_Per.Text + txtStreetNumber_Per.Text + txtArea_Per.Text + txtLandMark_Per.Text + txtCity_Per.Text + txtPinCode_Per.Text +
         txtState_Per.Text + txtTelephoneNum_Per.Text + txtMobileNum_Per.Text ==
         txtHouseNum_M.Text + txtStreetNum_M.Text + txtArea_M.Text + txtLandmark_M.Text + txtCity_M.Text + txtPinCode_M.Text +
         txtState_M.Text + txtTelephoneNum_M.Text + txtMobileNumber_M.Text)
     {
         condition1 = "'PC', 'PAC',  'TC', 'PEC', 'ADC', 'EPF', 'ESIC', 'EPS', 'GRAT', 'NOC'";
         condition2 = "'PEC', 'TC','PAC', 'PC', 'ADC', 'EPF', 'ESIC','EPS', 'GRAT', 'NOC'";
     }
     else
     {
         condition1 = "'PC','TC', 'PEC', 'ADC', 'EPF', 'ESIC','EPS', 'GRAT', 'NOC'";
         condition2 = "'PEC', 'TC', 'PC', 'ADC', 'EPF', 'ESIC','EPS', 'GRAT', 'NOC'";
     }
     if (chkPrevData.Checked == true)
     {
         dtAttach = CF.ExecuteDT("SELECT stuff((Select ',' + Type_desc from type_mst_a where Type_code = 'AC' " +
                                             "and NOT Type_Abbr in(" + condition1 + ") and type_abbr NOT IN (select category_id from EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS " +
                                             "where pk1_value = '" + txtEmpCode.Text + "')for xml path('')),1,1,'') Categories");
     }
     else
     {
         dtAttach = CF.ExecuteDT("SELECT stuff((Select ',' + Type_desc from type_mst_a where Type_code = 'AC' " +
                                             "and NOT Type_Abbr in(" + condition2 + ") and type_abbr NOT IN (select category_id from EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS " +
                                             "where pk1_value = '" + txtEmpCode.Text + "')for xml path('')),1,1,'') Categories");
     } */

    // Int32 intcnt = Convert.ToInt32(CF.ExecuteScaler("select count(*) cnt from EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS " +
    //                                        "where pk1_value = '" + txtEmpCode.Text + "' and category_id='PP'"));

    // if (dtAttach.Rows.Count > 0 && dtAttach.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
    if (strpmsg != "")
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CloseScript", "alert('Status of Attached file\\s are as \\n" + strerrmsg.ToString() + " ');", true);
    }
    else
    {   
        funsave();
    }
}
```

Thanks For all your suggestion friends.

Comment: Consider using `StringBuilder` instead of string interpolation :)

Comment: @Buzinas: yeah, will try with that too. thanks for your suggestion. have a nice day.!

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASP.NET Validation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
                <td>Birth Certificate:</td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" ID="TextBox1" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
                        ErrorMessage="Birth Certificate."
                        Display="dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>PAN Certificate:</td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" ID="TextBox2" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox2" 
                        ErrorMessage="PAN Certificate."
                        Display="dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>UAN Certificate:</td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" ID="TextBox3" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox3" 
                        ErrorMessage="UAN Certificate."
                        Display="dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Gratuity Certificate:</td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" ID="TextBox4" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox4" 
                        ErrorMessage="Gratuity Certificate."
                        Display="dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Nomination Certificate:</td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" ID="TextBox5" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
                        ErrorMessage="Nomination Certificate."
                        Display="dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Permanent Address:</td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="200px" ID="TextBox6" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox6" 
                        ErrorMessage="Permanent Address."
                        Display="dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="Summary" 
            DisplayMode="BulletList"
            HeaderText="Please attach files for the following documents:"
            ShowMessageBox="true"
            ShowSummary="False" />
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi jstreet. Thanks for ur reply. But this is not the solution what I wanted..my requirement is different. If possible go through my question you will get ab idea of what I want..